# For basic auth, can you use a key passed as params via url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, authentication

Not talking anything super sensitive or private. I have a situation where I just want to restrict access, and was going to use Rails' `authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic` method to require a password on a page. Then I realized, I could also just do that by having an extra parameter on the URL and comparing it with whatever I define. So something like:

```
www.mypage.com?secret=password

def page
    if params[:secret] == ENV["secret"]
        ...
    end
end
```

From a security perspective, why would this not be as secure as the Rails' method? What added security does the Rails' method provide?

Answer (score 0):

The level of security would be almost identical to basic authentication, except instead of two fields, you only need one.

Basic authentication provides no confidentiality for the username and password being passed in the header, unless you're working over HTTPS, which you should be anyways and this will be encrypted over HTTPS as well.

The only thing I'd say is that the URL could end up in the browser history and will show up in the address bar. So I guess in that way it is less secure, since if someone could gain access to your browser history, they could get the key.

I guess you just have to decide how secure you care for it to be.

I will add that Devise is a great Gem for managing authentication (kind of the standard, go to solution) and there are many great plugins for it to manage permissions as well on a user level basis. Although, I sense that it may be overkill for what you want.